# Agrupar varias filas con misma clave en una sola MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla que muestra los siguientes datos de los empleados de una empresa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera poder agrupar las filas que pertenecen a un mismo empleado, y que en la columna descHabilidad figuren todas sus habilidades.

Por ejemplo:

```
Gomez   |  Juan    |     110      |   Director     | Trabajo en equipo,
        |          |              | de Informática | Comunicación oral y
        |          |              |                | escrita, Liderazgo
```

Edito: El código que utilizo para obtener la tabla mostrada en la imagen es la siguiente (utilizo tablas normalizadas):

```
SELECT   persona.apellido,
         persona.nombre,
         persona.dniPersona,
         puesto.descPuesto,
         habilidades.descHabilidad
FROM persona
         INNER JOIN puesto_personas
ON persona.dniPersona = puesto_personas.dni_Persona
         INNER JOIN puesto
ON puesto_personas.cod_Puesto = puesto.codPuesto
         INNER JOIN persona_habilidades
ON persona.dniPersona = persona_habilidades.dni_Persona
         INNER JOIN habilidades
ON persona_habilidades.cod_Habilidad = habilidades.codHabilidad
```

Intenté agrupar las filas por el campo dniPersona, agregando lo siguiente al código anterior:

```
GROUP BY persona.dniPersona
```

Pero al hacerlo sólo se muestra una habilidad por empleado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias y saludos

Comment: Saludos, por favor agrega lo que intentaste para solucionar tu problema. ;)

Comment: Hola, gracias. Ya edité la publicación. Saludos

Comment: utiliza la funcion [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) de mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
 apellido,
 nombre,
 dniPersona,
 descPuesto,
 GROUP_CONCAT(desHabilidad) as habilidades
from persona
group by apellido, nombre, dniPersona, descPuesto
```

Para lograr lo que pides puedes usar la **función de agregación group_concat**, la cual concatena valores dentro de cada grupo definido por la **cláusula group by**, debes agrupar por los campos que te indico, ya que en **SQL** hay una regla de oro que dice que los campos que no aparecen en la **cláusula group by** deben aparecer en el **select** con una **función de agregación**, y en tu caso la función de agregación solo se aplica a un campo.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funcionó perfecto. Saludos!